CKR_TEMPLATE_INCONSISTENT error while creating key on the hsm
I am getting CKR_TEMPLATE_INCONSISTENT error while trying to create a key on the hsm. I am using PKCS11 C# wrapper.
public void GenerateKeyByName(ISession session, string keyName, string keyContent,string requestId)
        {
            byte[] ckaId = session.GenerateRandom(20);
            byte[] contentbyte = ConvertUtils.HexStringToBytes(keyContent);
            List<IObjectAttribute> objectAttributes = new List<IObjectAttribute>();

            objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_SECRET_KEY));
            objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_KEY_TYPE, CKK.CKK_AES));
            objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_TOKEN, true));
            objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_ENCRYPT, true));
            objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_DECRYPT, true));
            objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_PRIVATE, true));
            objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_LABEL, keyName));
            objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_ID, ckaId));
            objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_VALUE, contentbyte));

            objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_VALUE_LEN, 32));
            IObjectHandle objectHandle = session.CreateObject(objectAttributes);
        }

The code is working fine with the soft hsm but on network hsm I am getting this error.
objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_VALUE_LEN, 32));
This line was added later but it didn't help.
On Sam Paul's suggestion, I am using the following code but getting Method C_UnwrapKey returned CKR_WRAPPED_KEY_INVALID error.
    byte[] contentbyte = ConvertUtils.HexStringToBytes("33333333333333333333333333333333");

    int keySizeBytes = contentbyte.Length; // Ensures the length matches the ZMK provided
    byte[] ckaId = session.GenerateRandom(20);

    // Step 2: Create the Wrapping Key Attributes
    List<IObjectAttribute> wrappingKeyAttributes = new List<IObjectAttribute>()
    {
        session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_TOKEN, false),
        session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_PRIVATE, true),
        session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_SECRET_KEY),
        session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_KEY_TYPE, CKK.CKK_DES3), // Ensure 3DES
        session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_ENCRYPT, true), // Enable encryption
        session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_UNWRAP, true), // Enable wrapping
        session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_LABEL, "TempAESImportKey"),
    };  

    IObjectHandle wrappingKeyHandle = session.GenerateKey(session.Factories.MechanismFactory.Create(CKM.CKM_DES3_KEY_GEN), wrappingKeyAttributes);
    Console.WriteLine("Wrapping key created successfully.");

    IMechanism encryptMechanism = session.Factories.MechanismFactory.Create(CKM.CKM_DES3_ECB);
    byte[] encryptedData = session.Encrypt(encryptMechanism, wrappingKeyHandle, contentbyte);
    Console.WriteLine("Encryption done successfully.");

    List<IObjectAttribute> unwrappingKeyAttributes = new List<IObjectAttribute>()
    {
        session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_TOKEN, true),
        session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_PRIVATE, true),
        session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_SECRET_KEY),
        session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_KEY_TYPE, CKK.CKK_DES3),
        session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_ENCRYPT, true),
        session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_DECRYPT, true),
        session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_UNWRAP, true),
        session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_LABEL, "ZMK"),
    };

    IObjectHandle unwrappingKeyHandle = session.GenerateKey(session.Factories.MechanismFactory.Create(CKM.CKM_DES3_KEY_GEN), unwrappingKeyAttributes);
    Console.WriteLine("Unwrapping key created successfully.");
    // Step 5: Unwrap the ZMK using zmkValue as the wrapped data
    // Unwrap the ZMK
    IMechanism unwrapMechanism = session.Factories.MechanismFactory.Create(CKM.CKM_DES3_ECB);
    
    //IObjectHandle importedKeyHandle = session.UnwrapKey(unwrapMechanism, unwrappingKeyHandle, encryptedData, unwrappingKeyAttributes);
    IObjectHandle importedKeyHandle = session.UnwrapKey(unwrapMechanism, wrappingKeyHandle, encryptedData, unwrappingKeyAttributes);
    
    Console.WriteLine("ZMK imported successfully into the HSM.");


CKR_TEMPLATE_INCONSISTENT means there is an inconsistency in your attribute template. I see you're attempting to create a secret key using C_CreateObject with a known key value. Some HSMs (whether Network, PCI, USB, or Cloud-based) may disallow this type of operation. They may also disallow injecting a key as clear into HSM. If your HSM has that restriction then I see two issues in your code -

You should use C_GenerateKey for generating secret keys, or C_GenerateKeyPair for generating asymmetric keys.

Remove (CKA.CKA_VALUE, contentbyte) from your attribute template. You only need to pass the CKA_VALUE_LEN. HSM will generate the key and assign the value to CKA_VALUE.


If you want to create a key using a known value (byte[] contentbyte) then here's what you need to do.

generate a temporary secret key.. let's call it wrapping_key.
encrypt "contentbyte" using wrapping_key and store the encrypted key value in another variable.. let's call that variable "encrypted_contentbyte".
Unwrap your key using C_UnwrapKey function and encrypted_cotentbyte.

Hope this helps!

I tried this technique but getting CKR_WRAPPED_KEY_INVALID error. I put the code in my original post.

CKR_WRAPPED_KEY_INVALID means the key you're trying to unwrap is either of an invalid type or not valid at all. This error is also easy to reproduce: for example, if you wrap an AES key and then try to unwrap it as a DES3 key, you'll encounter CKR_WRAPPED_KEY_INVALID.
This error can also occur if your HSM has specific restrictions on key types or weak keys. For instance, if your HSM does not permit DES3 keys and you attempt to unwrap a key as DES3, the token will return CKR_WRAPPED_KEY_INVALID.

Support answer from @sam-paul
If you will use C_GenerateKey to generate new key don't forget to use CKM_AES_KEY_GEN mechanism.
